# How to tag Sins of a Solar Empire: Rebellion?

Tags: discussion, tags

[sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion) is too long.

Options:

1. [sins-rebellion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sins-rebellion)
2. [soase-rebellion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soase-rebellion)
3. [rebellion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebellion)
4. ???

Comment: Curse you, tag limit! *shakefist*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we have a 35 character tag limit, this ought to be retagged to [sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion), which matches the base game tag of [sins-of-a-solar-empire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sins-of-a-solar-empire).

I don't have the ability to create synonyms, or even make edits without approval. Could someone who has that power do this?

Answer (score 2):

[soase-rebellion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soase-rebellion) looks reasonable.

Comment: it just looks really weird :/  but soase on google does turn out to be sins of a solar empire

Comment: I'll go with it for now, if something changes they can go and edit my question tags.

Comment: @yx. SOASE, afaik, is a commonly used abbreviation. Renaming tags is easy so don't worry too much about it. "Sins-rebellion" is an okay alternative but... these two words probably also lead to a ton of hits about religion, Satan and whatnot.

Comment: lol good point about the religion stuff

Comment: [soase-rebellion] is good enough - if you search for "sins of a solar empire military victory", this question already shows up as one of the first page results on Google

Comment: Sounds too much like... Something else

Comment: @JuanManuel The early days of the internet have scarred us.

Comment: As a note, when you make a possibly confusing tag like this make sure you add a tag wiki excerpt

Comment: This discussion brings up another question: Why hasn't [soase] been made a tag simile for [sins-of-a-solar-empire]?  If I were to ever get back into SoaSE, that'd be my first choice for quickly searching.

Comment: @MBraedley Because no one created the [tag:soase] tag?

Comment: Now that we have a 35 character tag limit, can we change this to [sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion]?